# How to solve the following issue in Spark 3.0? Can not create the managed table. The associated location already exists.;

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark3

In my spark job, I tried to overwrite a table in each microbatch of structured streaming

```
batchDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("mytable")
```

It generated the following error.

```
  Can not create the managed table('`mytable`'). The associated location('file:/home/ec2-user/environment/spark/spark-local/spark-warehouse/mytable') already exists.;
```

I knew in Spark 2.xx, the way to solve this issue is to add the following option.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.allowCreatingManagedTableUsingNonemptyLocation","true")
```

It works well in spark 2.xx. However, this option was removed in Spark 3.0.0. Then, how should we solve this issue in Spark 3.0.0?

Thanks!

Comment: Please try to explicitly specify the path where you're going to save with the 'overwrite' mode.

Comment: Thanks John, I can confirm it works by adding a path in Spark 3.0.  The way I add the path is as following. ```batchDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).option("path", "/home/ec2-user/environment/spark/spark-local/tmp").saveAsTable("mytable")```. I am deploying in the standalone mode. Do you also have some comments on what is the correct path to use if I want to deploy it into hadoop cluster? Thanks!

Comment: does the "spark.sql.legacy.allowCreatingManagedTableUsingNonemptyLocation","true" also deletes the remaining files? otherwise, you might get a mix of old and new files.

Comment: I can confirm that this works: I am loading json format local hive tables in integration tests and have specified the same directory that was being used by default ( which is in my ide): now it doesn't fail if the files already exist.

Comment: @yyuankm Did you find a solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you run your test data generation and your actual test in the same process - can you just replace these with **createOrReplaceTempView** to save them to Spark's in-memory catalog instead of into a Hive catalog?

Something like : **batchDF.createOrReplaceTempView("mytable")**